# Logstash custom date format and irregular spaces

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, grok

Receiving a parsing failure with my grok match.  I can't seem to find anything that will match my log.

Here is my log:

> 2016-06-14    14:03:42    1.1.1.1 GET /origin-www.site.com/ScriptResource.axd?d= jEHA4v5Z26oA-nbsKDVsBINPydW0esbNCScJdD-RX5iFGr6qqeyJ69OnKDoJgTsDcnI1&t=5f9d5645  200 26222   0   "http://site/ layouts/CategoryPage.aspx?dsNav=N:10014"  "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; SM-G318HZ Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.95 Mobile Safari/537.36"    "cookie"

Here is my grok match.  It works fine in the grok debugger.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { 'message' => '%{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:time_taken} %{QUOTEDSTRING:referrer} %{QUOTEDSTRING:user_agent} %{QUOTEDSTRING:cookie}' }
  }
}
```

EDIT: I decided to do a screenshot of what my log file looks like as the spaces dont come over when copying and pasting.  Those appear to be single spaces when I copy/paste.

[image]

Comment: The logline you posted has a space in the URI params at `xd?d= jEHA4`

Comment: Yeah.  Sorry about that.  That doesnt exist in request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside the space in that logline you posted, which I assume won't exist in your logs, your pattern is incorrect on the date parsing. Logstash `DATE` follows this pattern:

```
DATE_US %{MONTHNUM}[/-]%{MONTHDAY}[/-]%{YEAR}
DATE_EU %{MONTHDAY}[./-]%{MONTHNUM}[./-]%{YEAR}
DATE %{DATE_US}|%{DATE_EU}
```

Which doesn't match your `YYYY-MM-dd` format. I recommend using a pattern file and defining a custom date format

```
CUST_DATE %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM2}-%{MONTHDAY}
```

then your pattern can be

```
%{CUST_DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:time_taken} %{QUOTEDSTRING:referrer} %{QUOTEDSTRING:user_agent} %{QUOTEDSTRING:cookie}
```

EDIT:
You may be able to handle weird whitespace with a gsub, this won't remove whitespace, but will normalize spaces to all be 1 " "

```
mutate {
    gsub => [
      # replace all whitespace characters or multiple adjacent whitespace characters with one space
      "message", "\s+", " "
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am seeing this now in the log.  "Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: Mapp
ing definition for [@time] has unsupported parameters:  [format : hh:mm:ss]", "c
aused_by"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"Mapping definition fo
r [@time] has unsupported parameters:  [format : hh:mm:ss]"}}}},

Comment: the funny thing is, I can't find anywhere I have defined time.  I created a custom pattern for time as well and I get the same error.

Comment: adding template_overwrite => true fixed the issue.

Comment: sorry got another issue.  Looks like my log files add a big space between log items.  They are single spaces but I think it is throwing off my pattern match.  the debugger doesnt even like these spaces.  is there anything that can be done?

2016-06-14 14:03:42 1.1.8.4 GET

Comment: If there are places where a space may or may not be put a `( )?` which is an optional space

Comment: Thank you for the response Will.  Doesn't seem to like that one either.  I have also tried + but that did't work either.  I don't know why the logs are saving like that.  It is still just a single space.  Maybe it is the format that they were sent

Comment: if its displaying like that it is definitely not just one space